# Execution failed for task ':app:multiDexListDebug'. A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm new to react native . when I run the react native via physical I got this error . And I tired to cleaned gradle and clean the npm still same error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:multiDexListDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Java heap space

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 37s
```

what's going wrong with is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62092231/react-native-task-appmultidexlistdebug-failed